# $(a \lor b) a a^*(a \lor a a^*b) \lor (a \lor b)aa^*aa^*$ is wrong?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, automata

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the non-deterministic finite automaton. I want to find the reguluar expression related to this diagram. I found $(a \lor b) a a^*(a \lor a a^*b) \lor (a \lor b)aa^*aa^*$, but it seems my answer is wrong. Where am I making an error?

Comment: Just like your previous questions, it is difficult to tell where you're going wrong, since all you have shared is the answer you got.

Comment: @Shaun What do you want me to provide? I can't provide the answer as I don't have it.

Comment: Explain how you got the answer you did.

Comment: Is $q_0$ both initial and final state?

Comment: @Shaun I modified the question.

Comment: That's better, @Alex; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$(a \cup b) (a \ (a \cup b)) ^*   aa^*\{b \ (a \cup b) (a \ (a \cup b)) ^*   aa^*\}^*$